# How to disable autofill in select tag

Tags: javascript, html, select, autocomplete, autofill

I can disable autofill in input tag.

But no matter how hard I try with the solution I found.

I cannot disable autofill in select tag.

Anybody could help？

Answer (score 0):

Solutions suggested: adding autocomplete="some-random-string" instead of autocomplete="off"

read more at "https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6075"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using autocomplete="none"
`<select class="form-select is-invalid" required aria-label="Select Country" oninput="selectCountry(this.value)" autocomplete="none" id="Country" name="Country">`

[Credit to solution is here](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8?permalink_comment_id=4143879#gistcomment-4143879)